# C# Visual studio code debug in live & trace it step-by step WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-debugging

I would like to learn and know, how can I examine my WPF application in **Visual Studio 2019** in running / debugging mode.
**Exactly what I expect:** how can I trace my code what step is executed in background if the application running( communicate with port; modifies string and so on...).

I would like to see what happening if I click on the button and it calls methods and those again do something . Like ***visually trace*** the behind code.

I used the breakpoints but tell the truth it is not that I am looking for. I would like if the VS can indicate  what line is executed e.g. if the textbox changed the code where continues and soo on. I think this way is existing. :)

The purpose of it **to find a intermitted failure** that I have made (maybe) even if it is not appears in every case and the VS not drop for it an exception. But the business requirement is not allowed that hidden failure/ unexpected slow processing, and I would like to find where it got stuck.

Someone can suggest what I have to use? In VS I also tried the in Debug menu-->Calls, Thread, Task window but these not give me that I want.

Comment: I doubt that's possible, especially with stuff going on in the background simultaneously. You probably wouldn't be able to read the currently highlighted line before it jumps to the next one. Your best take is setting a breakpoint on the button command and stepping through. Place some breakpoints on the way down and you'll get there as soon as they're hit again. Maybe using some event handlers is worth a try, e.g [`INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=net-6.0) if you're using MVVM.

Comment: @imsmn Thanks. I also thinking about the step into and step over function.... Maybe it is the most close that I looking for.

Comment: BWT, in totally other programming like Labview there is a visual trace in running mode as 'Highlight execution'.  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Rx6AXhF31I  

I am looking for something similar.... :) I am aware of that this language is totally different.  So, thank you once more. :)

Comment: You can use perftips to see how long processing took between breakpoints. Google perftips.  You couod also consider adding logging. Nlog is my preference. That has a time associated with each log entry and you could log data to show what's being processed. See roughly where the time is consumed and then see which area or areas need to be refined. The logging could be conditional and include stack trace. You can also insert conditional break points if you know what property value where indicates a problem.

Comment: Hi @Andy, Thanks! I have tried many ways and use conditional break points with step into and between my classes I finally found the root case of my problem. 
Once more thanks for your feedback. We can change the topic for solved.